# I am currently working on a MAC changer script, I am running into an error

Tags: python, penetration-testing

This is my code:

```
import subprocess
 
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface to change MAC adress")

parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="mac", help="new mac adress")

(options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()

interface = options.interface

mac = options.mac 

#print("(+) Your mac adress for " + interface + " has been changed to " + mac)

subprocess.call(["sudo ifconfig",interface, "down"])

subprocess.call(["sudo ifconfig",interface, "hw", "ether", mac])

subprocess.call(["sudo ifconfig",interface, "up"])
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "mac_changer.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["sudo ifconfig",interface, "down"])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1639, in _execute_child

    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not assigning a value to `interface`, therefore it is `NoneType`. Make sure that you're calling your script with `-i` and specifying a network interface.